# How to create any one dynamic controls with a for loop without using location property and the form should grow automatically

Tags: vb.net

How to create multiple button controls with a for loop without getting the controls overlapped and without using location property in Vb.Net. 
I have created 'n' number of vb controls dynamically but the created controls are getting overlapped to each other. When I use location property to each controls all the controls are getting displayed as per the location value. 
The real problem is, I'm using a panel of width 300 and height 300, under that I need to display the dynamically created controls. I have figured it out which is tedious work and does take a lot of time. My idea is to find the panel width and height then need to check whether the new control which is getting created has ample of space to fit inside the panel.

I need to know few things, 
1) How to display the controls dynamically using for loop without getting overlapped over each other and without using location property.
2) I need the container or the panel to grow as per the number of controls which gets created dynamically.
3) Accessing each controls which got displayed using an ID or educate or explain me any better idea.

Comment: You can use a `TableLayoutPanel` or a `FlowLayoutPanel` to position the controls automatically but the form won't grow on its own, so it's up to you to set the `Size` of the form based on the last `Button`.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new WinForms project and added a `Button` to the top of the form.  I added a `FlowLayoutPanel` under that and made it narrow enough to fit a single `Button` widthwise.  I set the `AutoSize` property of the FLP to `True` and the `FlowDirection` to `TopDown`.  I then added this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Create the new Button.
    Dim btn As New Button

    'Add it to the FLP
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn)

    'Get the position of the bottom, left of the Button relative to the form.
    Dim pt = PointToClient(btn.PointToScreen(New Point(0, btn.Height)))

    'Resize the form to provide clearance below the new Button.
    ClientSize = New Size(ClientSize.Width, pt.Y + 10)
End Sub
```

I then ran the project and started clicking the `Button` I added.  As expected, each click added a new `Button` to the FLP in a vertical column and the form resized to fit.  In order to access such controls in code, you can simply index the `Controls` collection of the FLP.

Answer (score 0):

try this helps you.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
       'Do Something
    Else
       'Do Something else
    End If

    Panel1.Controls.Clear()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10 Step 1
        Dim b15 As New Button
        b15.Text = "Test3"
        b15.ID = "a" & i
        AddHandler b15.Click, AddressOf updateFunc
        Panel1.Controls.Add(b15)
    Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is for ASP.NET and, while I can't be 100% sure, I suspect that the question relates to Windows Forms.  There's no reference to a page and it's asking how to resize a form based on the controls it contains, which would not be an issue in Web Forms.